# How to deploy ibm watson assistant chat bot to my already hosted website?

Tags: watson-conversation

I have created a chat bot using Watson assistant in IBM cloud and I want to add that chat bot to my website which is written using html. Can anyone please help me in solving this out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Watson Assistant API's/SDK to deploy it to your existing HTML Website.
Please refer here https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/assistant/api/v1/curl.html?curl

Additionally,you can refer this documentation as well https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/develop-app.html#building-a-client-application

Comment: Thank you for your response!! It did help me a lot.

Comment: @anjansreekarYou can mark it as answer if you feel it has helped you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

In case it is a wordpress blog, you can use an available plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/conversation-watson/